# Как сохранить в файл Shape, нарисованный в XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Я только начал изучать `WPF`, поэтому такой простой и наивный вопрос. Есть проект с графическим интерфейсом на `WPF`. На главном окне программы имеется кнопочка с иконкой. Моё задание было выдрать картинку и передать в другой проект. Меня охватил ужас от того, что я не могу найти файл в структуре solution. Иконка сделана с помощью тэга [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.data.aspx). Есть ли способ экспортировать это рисование в файл `png`?

Comment: Уважаемый Expert! Перейдите, пожалуйста по ссылке: http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%A3%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тот рисунок, который уже сделан в XAML (с помощью Path), правильно в виде XAML и сохранить. Так вы его всегда сможете переиспользовать в любом другом проекте WPF. Кроме того, можно 1) сконвертировать XAML в SVG или в AI, если нужно его еще куда-то вставить в векторном виде, 2) преобразовать в PNG, JPG, GIF и т.д., если его нужно еще куда-то вставить в растровом виде.

Можно установить Expression Blend, Illustrator или InkScape - они все понимают XAML (для Illustrator нужен плагин) и там обрабатывать картинку.

Пример.

Картинка в виде XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Name="svg2" Width="100" Height="100">
<Canvas.Resources/>
    <Canvas Name="layer1">
        <Canvas>
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <!--g-->
                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="-952.36218"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="26" Canvas.Top="979" Width="46" Height="47" Name="rect3003" Fill="#0000FF" Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Картинка в виде png:

[image: синий квадрат]

Сделано в InkScape.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что надо не в wpf проект. А можно ли без expression обойтись средствами VS?

Comment: В простых случая можно сделать снимок экрана, в сложных нужен какой-нибудь редактор.